# Algolia::AlgoliaProtocolError in rspec after gem upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, algolia

I started receiving Algolia::AlgoliaProtocolError after upgrading from 1.17.0 to 1.19.1

Full stack trace is below.

```
 Failure/Error: @listing = FactoryGirl.create :used_car_listing, user_id: another_user.id

 Algolia::AlgoliaProtocolError:
   Cannot reach any host: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (XXX.algolia.net:443), getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (XXX-3.algolianet.com:443), getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (XXX-1.algolianet.com:443), getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (XXX-2.algolianet.com:443)
 # /Users/****/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@****/gems/algoliasearch-1.12.7/lib/algolia/client.rb:365:in `request'
 # /Users/****/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@****/gems/algoliasearch-1.12.7/lib/algolia/client.rb:377:in `put'
 # /Users/****/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@****/gems/algoliasearch-1.12.7/lib/algolia/index.rb:431:in `set_settings'
 # /Users/****/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@****/gems/algoliasearch-rails-1.19.1/lib/algoliasearch-rails.rb:292:in `block (3 levels) in <class:SafeIndex>'
 # /Users/****/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@****/gems/algoliasearch-rails-1.19.1/lib/algoliasearch-rails.rb:327:in `log_or_throw'
 # /Users/****/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@****/gems/algoliasearch-rails-1.19.1/lib/algoliasearch-rails.rb:291:in `block (2 levels) in <class:SafeIndex>'
 # /Users/****/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@****/gems/algoliasearch-rails-1.19.1/lib/algoliasearch-rails.rb:750:in `algolia_ensure_init'
 # /Users/****/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@****/gems/algoliasearch-rails-1.19.1/lib/algoliasearch-rails.rb:552:in `block in algolia_index!'
 # /Users/****/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@****/gems/algoliasearch-rails-1.19.1/lib/algoliasearch-rails.rb:549:in `each'
 # /Users/****/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@****/gems/algoliasearch-rails-1.19.1/lib/algoliasearch-rails.rb:549:in `algolia_index!'
 # /Users/****/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@****/gems/algoliasearch-rails-1.19.1/lib/algoliasearch-rails.rb:893:in `algolia_index!'
 # /Users/****/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@****/gems/algoliasearch-rails-1.19.1/lib/algoliasearch-rails.rb:912:in `algolia_enqueue_index!'
 # /Users/****/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@****/gems/algoliasearch-rails-1.19.1/lib/algoliasearch-rails.rb:942:in `algolia_perform_index_tasks'
 # ### REMOVED FOR BREVITY
 # /Users/****/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@****/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:20:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
 # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/images_controller_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: mmhan, it could be probably due to the configuration. Algolia indexing is working in development?
And what are you trying to test?

Comment: you are trying to talk to servers that are not reachable through you network `getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (XXX.algolia.net:443), getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided`

Comment: @MatayoshiMariano Algolia's indexing is disabled for test environment, and thus the test cases were working before the upgrade. The only change that broke the build was the upgrade.

Comment: @phoet Your comment is still not helpful. Algolia is trying to connect to its server even when indexing is explicitly disabled.

Comment: @mmhan did you do [this](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails#testing)?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you've set `XXX` as the your Algolia ApplicationID because you're running tests and you don't want them to call the actual API. Unfortunately, looks like the gem is trying to call the API and therefore tries to contact `XXX.algolia.net` -> which is unreachable...

Are you mocking the calls (using WebMock) or disabling the indexing through the `algoliasearch` block? Could you tell us more about how you're "disabling" the Algolia indexing in your tests?

Comment: I'll stop duplicating my comments here. Since we are already talking to each other on github @redox